# error: "Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:4200/api/login" angular2 project

Tags: angular, http, express

I was directed to use:

```
this.http.post('/api/login', this.employeeId).subscribe(res => { this.router.navigate(['/select']), (err) => {console.log(err)}})
```

as a way to get to the controller of my server router, which looks like this:

```
router.post('/login', home_controller.employee_login);
```

Is there a syntax error? or am I misunderstood on the routes somehow?
source code: [nodequiz project](https://github.com/davidtays/web-450)

Comment: `localhost:4200` is your development server from webpack. Your `api` url is probably different. What you can do is set up proxy on angular-cli, here's the [angular cli doc for proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: I edited the code but it did not change.  I have code in my app.js file that says     app.use('/api', homeRouter);
And in my proxy is     "/" with target option of      "http://localhost:3000/api"

Comment: I also use the changeOrigin and have it set to true

Comment: You want to route that to `/api` not `/` on your proxy config. Then your target is just `https://localhost:3000`

Comment: That is working, as now I am getting errors that show I'm in the controller. thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to run two bashes terminal.
The first terminal with "npm run server"
and
the second terminal with "npm start.

This work well for me.